# Proving that an expression is not a polynomial

Tags: polynomials

So I know what a polynomial is. For example, we know that $$5x^8+9x^2+x-700$$ is a polynomial.

If an expression contains the sine function, then it can still be a polynomial? For instance, the expression $$\sin{x}-\sin{x}$$ is a polynomial even though is contains the sine function. It's obvious to me that $\sin{x}$ is not a polynomial, but I'm not sure how to prove it.

More generally, given an expression, how do we determine if it's a polynomial or not?

As I showed in the example $\sin{x}-\sin{x}$, a polynomial doesn't have to "look" like the form: $$a_nx^n+\cdots+a_1x+a_0$$

One direction I thought of was that a polynomial has only a finite number of roots, so if we have an expression that has an infinite number of roots (like $\sin{x}$) then it's not a polynomial. But not every expression with a finite number of roots is a polynomial (like $5^x-5$).

Comment: Of course $f(x)-f(x)=0$ is the zero polynomial for *any* function. You have also asked why $\sin(x)$ is not a polynomial. This has been asked very often. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1568644/show-that-sin-x-cannot-be-polynomial-using-the-concept-of-boundedness) for example, how to prove it. In general, there is rarely such a problem. If a function doesn't look like $a_nx^n+\cdots a_1x+a_0$, then it is usually not a polynomial. $\sin(x)-\sin(x)$ is not an argument against it. Other "trivial" disguises are $f(x)=(x^2-1)/(x-1)=(x+1).$

Comment: The expression $5^x-5$ is not a polynomial since it has an infinite number of roots (over $\mathbb{C}$).

Comment: Plenty of polynomial properties already listed in the answers, but another: if $f$ is a polynomial (other than the zero constant function), then $\lim_{x \to \pm \infty} \frac{\ln |f(x)|}{\ln |x|}$ is a non-negative integer, which is the leading term's exponent.

Comment: Your question is kinda vague. In general to determine whether a generic function is polynomial could be very hard. For example, how do you know $\exp(\frac{(\ln x)^2}{\ln(x^2+2)})$ is not a polynomial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Definition:** The difference table is constructed by subtracting adjacent entries in a sequence repeatedly.
We start with the sequence in the first column, say $a_1, a_2, \ldots$.
The second column is calculated as $b_1 = a_2 - a_1, b_2 = a_3 - a_2, \ldots$.
The third column is calculated as $c_1 = b_2 - b_1, c_2 = b_3 - b_2, \ldots$.

**Theorem:** Suppose we have an infinite series of values $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n, \ldots$. Then there exists a polynomial such that $f(i) = a_i$ if and only if the difference table has a column that is all 0.
There are other useful facts too, like:

- If the $k+1$th difference is all 0, then the polynomial has degree at most $k$.
- If the $k$th column is a non-zero constant $a$, then the leading term is $ \frac{a}{ k!} x^{k}$.
- $f(x)$ can be obtained in closed form using just values in the first row.

Note: Just because $f(1), f(2), \ldots $ can be expressed as a polynomial, doesn't mean that $f$ is a polynomial. For example, $f(x) = x + \sin \pi x$.

**Almost immediate Corollaries:**

1. Polynomials tend to infinity. In particular, $\frac{1}{x^2 + 1 } , 2^x $ cannot be expressed as a polynomial.
2. Polynomials are defined everywhere. In particular, $ \tan x, \frac{1}{x}$ are not polynomials.
3. The sum of a polynomial and a non-polynomial is a non-polynomial.
4. If the difference table is never 0, then it cannot be expressed as a polynomial. In particular, the Fibonacci numbers cannot be expressed as a polynomial as the $k$th column has entries $k_i = F_{i-k}$, which isn't eventually 0.

**Corollaries that requires some work:**

1. The only periodic functions which are polynomials are the constant functions. In particular, the trigonometric functions (and their non-zero sums and differences) cannot be expressed as a polynomial.
2. $x^r$ is a polynomial if and only if $r$ is a non-negative integer.
3. Sums and differences of exponential functions cannot be expressed as a polynomial, unless it is the zero function. (Fibonacci numebrs are a special case of this.)

Answer (score 0):

A polynomial is defined as any expression of the form you wrote above: $a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1x+a_0$ whereas:

$a)$ $n$ is a natural number.

$b)$ $a_n,a_{n-1},\cdots, a_0$ are constant real numbers.

Note that a polynomial is continuous and defined for all real numbers in addition to being of the form above. The followings examples are **not** polynomials:

$a)$ $y = 2^x$ since the $x$ is the exponent and is not constant.

$b)$ $y = \dfrac{1}{x}$ since it is not defined for $x = 0$.

$c)$ $y = \cos x$ since it cannot be expressed using a finite number of terms.

$d)$ $y = \sqrt{x}$ since its exponent is not a natural number.

Comment: in your answer you  didn't make it clear why a and d cannot be written as some polynomial; one might prove that, for example, using limits